# adding size to private array - java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new to Java programming and wanted to try my hand at a little bit outside of my classes. I've created a class that will manipulate arrays, so I set up a private array with no size allocated to it. In a public constructor, how do I set the size of this array?

Comment: you just initialize the array like you would anywhere else

Comment: Can you share the code you have, and explain what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I think I've got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ClassName()
{
  arr = new int[10];
}
```

Remember that the Constructor is the method called when an object is instantiated. The Constructor must be a method with no return type and the same name as the class. You could even take in parameters if you'd like to(say a size variable), then create a new array based on the size.

For instance, you could do this:

```
public ClassName(int size)
{
   arr = new int[size];
}
```

Now when in your tester class,  you could create a new object using that constructor.

```
ClassName c = new ClassName(5);
```

Which creates a new object with an array of size 5 as a class variable. Hope this helped!

Edit: I should add; if you do not specify a constructor, Java will do it for you, but it will do nothing.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!!

Comment: Actually, the default constructor (the one provided by the compiler absent any declared constructor) doesn't do "nothing", it does potentially quite a lot, and always does something.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in must of the languages.

example:

```
anArray = new int[10]; //10 - array size, int is the array type
```

read about [JAVA Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)